# Unity 5 missing Standard Assets

Tags: unity, assets

I have Unity 5 and when I make a new project, there are no assets that are usually there (Character Controller, Terrain, etc.). How do I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to http://unity3d.com/get-unity/download?ref=personal click on "ADDITIONAL DOWNLOADS
FOR WINDOWS" and select "[Standard Assets](http://netstorage.unity3d.com/unity/5b98b70ebeb9/WindowsStandardAssetsInstaller/UnityStandardAssetsSetup.exe)".

Answer (score 3):

Select `Window` from the top menu, and open the `Asset Store`. On the right hand side of the page there is a list of categories. Select the `Unity Essentials` category. This category contains a number of asset packages published by Unity Technologies. Included in this pack is the `Standard Assets` package.

You'll also find a number of other packages that have great quality assets and they're all free.

[image]